# If the heights of two triangles are proportional then prove that they are similiar

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

We have two different triangles $\triangle ABC$ and  $\triangle A'B'C'$.
Now we have a relation between heights $AH$ and  $A'H'$.Actually $H$ and $H'$ are the points on $BC$ and $B'C'$ sides. $$\frac{AH}{A'H'}=x$$
Now we must prove that  $$ \triangle ABC \thicksim \triangle A'B'C'$$
Actually I have done something. But unhopefully no results!
If  $\triangle ABC$ and  $\triangle A'B'C'$ are similiar then we have:
$$\frac{AC}{A'C'}= \frac{AB}{A'B'}= \frac{BC}{'BC'}$$
But it must be proved and we don't know that it is true or not.

And 
$$AH=AC\sin\angle C$$
$$A'H'=A'C'\sin\angle C'$$
Now any ideas to prove that these triangles are similiar?!

Comment: There is definitely some key information missing here. **Every** pair of triangles satisfies that their heights are in some relation. Please provide the full problem description.

Comment: What do you mean @maxmilgram ? I explained everething about the problem and there is no anything else!

Comment: even for given $x$ there are countless examples of triangles that satisfy your condition that are not similar. Thus your problem can not be solved. Trust me, there is definitely some key information missing!

Comment: Something is missing if it is only the height from $A$ (in one triangle) and the height from $A'$ (in the other) we have information on. One height alone cannot determine the "shape" of a triangle, i.e. specification of one height alone cannot force a triangle to be similar to another given triangle. Maybe you have information on the other heights, say $BI$, $CJ$, $B'I'$, $C'J'$, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense, to me, saying that **one** pair of anything is proportional. So I take for granted the OP meant that the **three pairs** of attitudes are proportional,
that is
$$\frac{h_a}{h^\prime_a} = \frac{h_b}{h^\prime_b} = \frac{h_c}{h^\prime_c}.$$

In this case, it is easy to imply that the two triangles are similar, because $h_a,h_b,h_c$ are reversely proportional to $a,b,c$. More precisely
$$\frac{h_a}{h_a^\prime} = \frac{2S/a}{2S^\prime/a^\prime} = \frac{a^\prime}{a} \cdot \color{red}{\frac S{S^\prime}},$$
and so
$$\frac{a^\prime}a = \frac{b^\prime}{b} = \frac{c^\prime}c.$$

Comment: Yes that is the point i meaned! A big thanks to you Quaung.

Comment: @user602338 np, I just made an edit (in red) for more precise argument.

Comment: Thanks! It's  very good

Comment: Just say that you mean S is ab/2?

Comment: Yes, $S= ah_a/2$ is the area.

Comment: That's not what the problem asks though. Do you understand now why others were telling you that some assumptions are missing? Don't expect people to guess.